# Working with SSL on the development box

Tags: ssl, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to make sure that my web application works with HTTPS for secure account information.  So I followed Hanselman's blog post to set it up:

[Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

Everything was working like mentioned.  However a couple of weeks ago it stopped working with the following error:

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

I did not change anything on the local box or my code except for Windows updates.  Can anyone tell me whats wrong?  I can explain more if more clarification is required.

My application is an MVC4 application with a SQL Server DB.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by following the steps described in [a post from scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

The following steps fixed the issue for me:

1. `makecert -r -pe -n "CN=<SOMENAME>" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku
   1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12`
2. `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300`
3. Look up the thumbprint of the certificate by using MMC.exe
4. `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 appid={<SOMEGUID>} certhash=<THUMBPRINT>`